# Prove that N is a subgroup of G and G/N and set of all real number under addition is isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Problem**

Let $G$ be the set of all functions with $D_G$ be the domain of $G$ where $D_G=[0,1] \in \mathbb{R}$ and $C_G$ be the codomain of $G$ where $C_G=\mathbb{R}$, that defined by $G=\lbrace f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} | f: function \rbrace$.
Defined the "+" operation in $G$ by
$(\forall f_1,f_2 \in G)(\forall x \in [0,1])$,

$(f_1+f_2)(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$,

such that $G$ is a group under addition.

If $N = \lbrace f \in G | f(\frac{1}{4})=0 \rbrace$, show that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G / N \cong (\mathbb{R},+)$.

Here I tried so far. Please correct me if I wrong. Thanks for help in advanced.

**My Solution (update)**

First, we'll show that $(\forall f_1,f_2\in N).f_1f_2^{-1} \in N \Rightarrow N$ subgroup of $G$.

Let $f_1,f_2 \in N$. Since $G$ group, then
$f_2^{-1} = -f_2 \in N$. Thus,
$f_1f_2^{-1}: (f_1 + (-f_2))(x)$

$=f_1(x)-f_2(x) = 0 \in N$, where $x=\frac{1}{4}$. Hence, $N$ is subgroup of $G$.

Next, we'll show that $G/N \cong \mathbb{R}$. Consider the mapping $k:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$k(f)=f(\frac{1}{4})$.

Note that $k(f_1+f_2)=(f_1+f_2)(\frac{1}{4}) = f_1(\frac{1}{4}) + f_2(\frac{1}{4})$. Thus, $k$ is a homomorphism.
Next, pick any real number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the constant function $f(x)=r, \forall x \in [0,1]$.
Then, $k(f)=f(\frac{1}{4})=r$. So, $k$ is surjective. Next,

$Ker \ k = \lbrace f \in G | k(f)=0 \rbrace$

$= \lbrace f \in G | f(\frac{1}{4}) = 0 \rbrace = N$.

Then, let $f_1,f_2 \in G$. Suppose $k(f_1)=k(f_2) \Rightarrow f_1(\frac{1}{4}) = f_2(\frac{1}{4})$. Thus, $f_1 = f_2$. Hence, $k$ is injective.

Hence, $G/N \cong (\mathbb{R},+)$.

Comment: To show that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$, you need to use the composition that you defined on $G$, i.e. you need to show that if $f_1,f_2\in N$, then $f_1-f_2\in N$. You are looking at $G$ as group under addition, not functional composition (the latter doesn't even make sense and it also doesn't really make sense to talk about $f_2^{-1}$ as $f_2$ need not be bijective).

Comment: The inverse in the group is not the inverse function (it doesn’t even exist for all functions). The inverse of $f$ in the group is simply $-f$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for correction.

Comment: how about my update?

Comment: $[0,1]$ may be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but it’s not an element of $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: I think you're going at it backwards. Start by defining $k$ as you do; show it is a homomorphism as you do; show it is onto as you do; calculate the kernel as you do. Now kernels are normal subgroups automatically and the quotient is iso to the image.

Comment: is my way true in showing that $N$ is subgroup of $G$ ?